# Emacs Perl mode: Send script/buffer to Perl interpreter?

Tags: perl, emacs

Say I am editing a Perl file or buffer in Emacs in the default Perl mode (the one that comes with Emacs 23.1.1).

Is there a way to directly send the full file (or buffer) to the Perl interpreter and see the result (on a separate buffer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are third party modes for running inferior perl processes and interacting with them (e.g. [`inf-perl.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/inf-perl.el)), but nothing that comes included with emacs 23.1.1.

However, an easy way to run your buffer with perl is with `shell-command-on-region`.  For example, this function will run perl on your buffer and display the output in a buffer called `*Perl Output*`:

```lisp
(defun perl-on-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "perl" "*Perl Output*")
  (display-buffer "*Perl Output*"))
```

Run it in a perl buffer with <kbd>M-x perl-on-buffer</kbd> or bind it to a key like so:

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'perl-mode
  '(define-key perl-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'perl-on-buffer))
```

Another option is to use `compile`/`recompile` with `perl <filename>` as the compile command.  This works on the file contents rather than the buffer contents, and has the added advantage of navigating errors with <kbd>C-x `` ` ``</kbd> (`next-error`).